# Post Request not receiving any Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a PostRequest from Unity that creates a new account in a database. When I run the Post Request function(click the submit button), a new Account is created in the database but all of the values are null. I am unable to get any of the data at the controller. I am sending the data as a string in Json format. Any help is appreciated.

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromForm] Account data )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data user name: " +data.userName);
        db.Accounts.Add(data);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        return "success";
    }
```

**PostRequest from Unity**

```
    public void AddAccount()
    {

    WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44301/accounts" );
    request.Method = "POST";

    string json = " { \"highScores\":[],\"lazyLoader\":{},\"userName\":user\",\"password\":testpassword",\"displayName\":name"} ";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    Debug.Log(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

    using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Debug.Log(responseFromServer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the username also ends up being 'user' as well?

Comment: Everything ends up being null. 'data' is an account object, but all parameter are null except the self-created id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending content body with type `application/json`. Form datas are sent via `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to change parameter binder `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` on your controller action.

Secondly, `" { \"highScores\":[],\"lazyLoader\":{},\"userName\":user\",\"password\":null,\"displayName\":null} "` is not a valid Json. When you change to `FromBody` binder, the deserializer will throw serialization exception. You need to fix the json data, also.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Unity has a built-in 'ToJson' function, I was able to use that.